# How to share sessions between different domain names in same rails app and same server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two domains like 'example.com' and 'website.com'. These domains hit the `same server` and `same Rails 4 app` connected with single db. By using route constraints, I have redirected to the required domain url's. This Rails app is running via Apache through passenger.

If user is logged in to example.com, it needs to share the login session with website.com directly. Not only authentication sessions but also, if I set any session variable in 'example.com' before login, that session should also be shared with 'website.com'. (vice versa)

Example:

Session like session[:example] = "1234" in example.com, That session should be shared with website.com

I am using 'devise' for flexible authentication in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, there is no easy way to do it. Rails sessions are based on cookies, and cookies can not be shared between domains. (They can only be shared between subdomains e.g. `api.someapp.com` and `someapp.com`).

For authenticated users you can use/build some kind of SSO solution which will store the session on the server and issue some kind of a session ID for every  domain used.

For non-authenticated users you can choose one of your domains as a 'primary' one and perform a small jsonp/iframe/whatever request to that domain, thus you will be able to share the data between domains.

But all that stuff is much more complicated that using stock Rails sessions.

Answer (score 0):

[Someone share this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38778657/21087) of using an iframe on another SO question. Haven't tried it though.
Also, [here is another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554120/rails-devise-and-multiple-domains) using Devise authenticatable feature that looks cleaner.